# On which site can I ask about websites?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about Google, but not about SEO or code. I want to know if someone knows if Google Search (*no* different URL and *no* plugins) let me include and prioritize Google history/bookmark results. And similar questions.

Comment: Not sure. I think [web apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions) will do.

Comment: You'll get better advice if you include the question here as a sample

Comment: @random I think I include it.

Comment: hey @BhuvanRikka you just solved my question, thank you very much.

Comment: @raulricardo21 Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, based on your information provided so far. [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) fits the description

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, **Google**, or any other **website which behaves like an application**
> - Browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!